# If $X \cup \{\infty\}$ is compact, then $X$ is locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In a textbook I'm reading, I have a topological space $X$ (which is a subspace of $L^{\infty}(E) \setminus \{0\}$ for some topological space $E$), such that $X \cup \{0\}$ is weak*-compact (in this case $L^{\infty}(E)$ is seen as the dual of $L^1(E)$).

Then, they say: "therefore, $X$ is locally compact". Apparently, $X$ is not a closed subspace of $X \cup \{0\}$. I don't understand why they conclude that $X$ is locally compact. I can give more context if necessary.

Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open subset $O$ of a (completely regular, but that's no problem here, all topological vector spaces are) locally compact space $X$ is locally compact.

This follows because for Hausdorff locally compact spaces, being locally compact is equivalent to having a base of open neighbourhoods with compact closure, and any point in $O$ will have that as well (just make sure we only consider those neighbourhoods whose closure lies in $O$, which we can always do by regularity).

Comment: Oh thank you! Here I have a locally compact space $X \cup \{0\}$ (even compact!), and $X$ is an open subspace of it, so it is locally compact (e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120648 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243147). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's the argument.